# Remove all folders by name

Tags: python

I need to delete all folders where folder name begins with "tmp****".

Example folder structure:
`C:/tmp` folder has `tmp323` `tmp543` `tmp922` folders inside.

Comment: I heard about regular expressions, but idk how to use properly in python.

Comment: If you are familiar with regex, you may use `re` and `glob`.

Comment: i've seen how with glob i can find files, but i need folders

Comment: You only need to check if the line startswith `tmp ` which `str.startswith` would do but you should provide the code that gets you to that point,

Comment: it might be a good idea to use the os package to figure out whether something is a directory, instead of just relying on the regex conventions.

Comment: @Eugene: you can even find dirs, read my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using glob, os and shutil:

```
import glob, os, shutil
dirs = glob.glob("tmp*/")
for dir in dirs:
    shutil.rmtree(dir)
```

Comment: I prefer this answer, as it is the least hacky and not re-inventing the wheel. You just need to be sure that you are actually dealing with directories when passing it to `rmtree`, otherwise its fine.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I updated my code adding `/` to match only dirs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to use

```
import glob
import os
```

in your program.  both are standard library programs.

glob will help you filter

```
glob.glob("tmp*")
```

and you will need to use some routines of the os package to determine if something is a directory.

once you have the list of directories to delete

```
for mydir in DirectoriesToDelete:
    os.system("rm -rf %s" %mydir)
```

or something close to that should do the trick.

Comment: the routine in os you might want to use is:  os.path.isdir

Comment: Or. map(os.removedirs, glob.glob("tmp*"))

Comment: I really like that functional approach @dekomote

Comment: Many thanks to all. this python is so flexible.

Comment: @tipanverella I doubt `rm -rf` will work on a windows box (as the OP probably is on)

Answer (score 0):

```
from os import listdir, rmdir
from os.path import isdir, join
mypath = "C:/tmp"
onlydirs = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isdir(join(mypath,f)) and f.startswith("tmp")]
for f in onlydirs: rmdir(join(mypath,f))
```